# Overflow in exp in scipy/numpy in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

What does the following error:

```
Warning: overflow encountered in exp
```

in scipy/numpy using Python generally mean?  I'm computing a ratio in log form, i.e. log(a) + log(b) and then taking the exponent of the result, using exp, and using a sum with logsumexp, as follows:

```
c = log(a) + log(b)
c = c - logsumexp(c)
```

some values in the array b are intentionally set to 0. Their log will be -Inf.

What could be the cause of this warning?  thanks.

Comment: Well, just take a look at the result of log(a)-log(b), then you will know why it is overflowing.

Comment: could you tell us more about what you are trying to do ? Are you trying to implement logsumexp ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your case, it means that `b` is *very* small somewhere in your array, and you're getting a number (`a/b` or `exp(log(a) - log(b))`) that is too large for whatever dtype (float32, float64, etc) the array you're using to store the output is.

Numpy can be configured to

1. Ignore these sorts of errors,
2. Print the error, but not raise a warning to stop the execution (the default)
3. Log the error,
4. Raise a warning
5. Raise an error
6. Call a user-defined function

See [`numpy.seterr`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html) to control how it handles having under/overflows, etc in floating point arrays.

Answer (score 9):

When you need to deal with exponential, you quickly go into under/over flow since the function grows so quickly. A typical case is statistics, where summing exponentials of various amplitude is quite common. Since the numbers are very big/smalls, one generally takes the log to stay in a "reasonable" range, the so-called log domain:

```
exp(-a) + exp(-b) -> log(exp(-a) + exp(-b))
```

Problems still arise because exp(-a) will still underflows up. For example, exp(-1000) is already below the smallest number you can represent as a double. So for example:

```
log(exp(-1000) + exp(-1000))
```

gives -inf (log (0 + 0)), even though you can expect something like -1000 by hand (-1000 + log(2)). The function logsumexp does it better, by extracting the max of the number set, and taking it out of the log:

```
log(exp(a) + exp(b)) = m + log(exp(a-m) + exp(b-m))
```

It does not avoid underflow totally (if a and b are vastly different for example), but it avoids most precision issues in the final result

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use this method to solve this problem:

> Normalized

I overcome the problem in this method. Before using this method, the accuracy my classify is :86%. After using this method, the accuracy of my classify is :96%!!!
It's great!
first:
[Min-Max scaling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3VmJo.gif)

[image: Min-Max scaling]

second:
[Z-score standardization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BYs0q.png)

[image: Z-score standardization]

These are common methods to implement `normalization`.
I use the first method. And I alter it. The maximum number is divided by 10. 
So the maximum number of the result is 10. Then exp(-10) will be not `overflow`!
I hope my answer will help you !(^_^)

Comment: This is off topic. The question is "What could be the cause of this warning?". It is not related to normalization for machine learning.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't `exp(log(a) - log(b))` the same as `exp(log(a/b))` which is the same as `a/b`?

```
>>> from math import exp, log
>>> exp(log(100) - log(10))
10.000000000000002
>>> exp(log(1000) - log(10))
99.999999999999957
```

---

2010-12-07: If this is so "some values in the array b are intentionally set to 0", then you are essentially dividing by 0. That sounds like a problem.

Comment: it is the same as long as you ignore precision issue - which matters quite often when you start taking exponential of numbers. Maybe the OP is trying to implement something like logsumexp

Comment: I am using logsumexp -- see revision of edited post -- will this make a difference?

Comment: @David Cournapeau: Meaning that the answer that uses logs and exp is less precise, right? Division is more accurate, I'd have thought. Just for my information.

Comment: @look at my own answer for an explanation of the issue when dealing with exponentials

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was due to large values in the data. I had to normalize (divide by 255, because my data was related to images) to get the values scaled down.